# Validating decimal input in increments of 15

Tags: infopath, column, validation

I have created a time entry form using a SharePoint list and InfoPath. One of the requirements is a column called 'Time spent' where they are to input the amount of time they spent on a project. It was requested in this format: *HH.MM – 15 minute increments*. The column type is currently a Number, and they do not wish to ask for date/time ranges.

Could anyone please offer some advice on a way to approach this? I am open to trying column validation through SharePoint or using rules in InfoPath.

I am using SharePoint Online 2016 and InfoPath 2013.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this?

```
=TRUNC(MOD((Number-TRUNC(Number))*100,15))=0
```

Number-TRUNC(Number) returns the decimal part

Multiply that by 100 to get it in whole numbers

Do a MOD 15 statement against that, the remainder should be 0. The final trunc is to get around decimal precision problems.

Comment: This works beautifully. Thank you for taking the time to help and explaining your answer.

Comment: I overlooked this, but it should be `=TRUNC(MOD((Number-TRUNC(Number))*100,25))=0` to convert the hour to decimal. (15 minutes, quarter hour)